# How to skip the creation of landscape thumbnails for an original portrait image

Tags: images

Let's have some thumbnail sizes like that:

```
    add_image_size('home-slide-medium', 1000, 504, true); 
    add_image_size('home-slide-sm', 500, 252, true);
    add_image_size('video-poster', 780, 512);
```

And let's upload a portrait image with size like `1000x3000px`

How can avoid the creation of the landscape thumbnails (like `1000x504` or `500x252`) for this portrait image?

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
    add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'custom_image_resize_dimensions', 10, 6 );
      function custom_image_resize_dimensions( $payload, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop ){



   // ie parameters: null, 1000, 3000, 1000, 500, true
   // ie payload: array(0, 0, 0, 1248, 1000, 504, 1000, 504))

    // if $crop is true...
    if($crop ) {

     // ...and if src img is portrait, skip it unless is same aspect ratio
    if($dest_w > $dest_h) {
        return false;
    }
    // else continue
    else {
        return $payload;
    }
}

else {
    return $payload;
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were headed in the right direction. There is another filter out there that handles `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced`. You can add or remove custom sized thumbnails in there. Rather than NOT creating your landscape custom sizes on a Portrait upload, maybe try to only create the landscape custom sizes on a landscape upload.

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', function( $sizes, $metadata ) {
  // Let's make sure we have the meta data we need before proceeding
  if(!empty($metadata['width']) && !empty($metadata['height'])){
    // Now let's make sure we have a Landscape being uploaded
    if($metadata['width'] > $metadata['height']){
      $sizes['home-slide-medium'] = array(
        'width' => 1000,
        'height' => 504,
        'crop' => true
      ); 
      $sizes['home-slide-sm'] = array(
        'width' => 500,
        'height' => 252,
        'crop' => tru
      e);
      $sizes['video-poster'] = array(
        'width' => 780,
        'height' => 512,
        'crop' =>false
      ); 
    }
  }

  return $sizes;
}, 10, 2);
```

I tested it a few times on my end, but let me know whatcha think!!

Comment: Thanks Cristopher, I've to say that also my solution works, the problem was elsewhere, however I've corrected the code to highlight better the parameters and the output. Thanks for your answer the perfectly completes the full frame!